# Windows 10 computer taking longer to boot after cloning old SSD to an upgraded SSD

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, samsung-ssd

Somewhat recently I cloned the SSD that came preinstalled with my Dell G15 laptop to a 2TB Samsung 980 Pro. The clone was done using Samsung Magician.

The procedure was extremely straightforward and no issues were encountered; just performed the clone and swapped the M.2 SSDs.

Something I noticed immediately was that bootup now took a lot longer than before which made no sense to me, because the SSD is now upgraded to a much faster one, and it's a clone, so in theory nothing changed as far as settings go. It should boot faster now, not slower.

Only within the past few days have I started to actually care about this and want to try to fix it. Timing the bootup, it takes at least around 50 seconds on average. Which if I had to guess is about 30 seconds longer than bootup took before the upgrade.

I have checked startup programs, and disabled a few with no real change to the bootup time. And again, I have the same startup programs from before since this is a clone.

I reordered the boot order in BIOS to have this drive come first, above Windows Boot Manager, the IPV4 and IPV6 and other boots, which changed nothing.

I inserted a Windows 10 install USB flash drive, booted into it, and ran the Startup Repair, which claimed it "couldn't repair [the] PC".

I'm not sure what else to try, everything that comes up from searching is general tips about speeding up boot time, but I believe my issue to be directly related to swapping to a cloned drive.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Driver issue, errors from source carried into new system. These are the obvious things.

Comment: @John As far as I can tell all relevant drivers are up to date. And if it's an error carried over from the old drive, I'm not sure why the old drive didn't have this issue.

Comment: I am not sure what other reasons would cause the slowdown you are experiencing